# Force system crash on hard hang

Tags: windows

I see that there is a way to force a system crash from keyboard.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545499(v=vs.85).aspx

But does this work when the system is hard hung? i.e, when the keyboard is not responding?

Comment: Just because you hit keys and nothing happens doesn't mean the keyboard is not functional. There is a major difference in how the signal from a USB keyboard and a PS2 keyboard travel. In that respect, it makes a difference on exactly what caused the hang. In most cases, you'll always have a better chance of a PS2 keyboard getting a signal through.

Comment: Oh Ok. I was using a USB keyboard. And it did not help when I tried to force the crash during hang. May be I should try a PS2 keyboard if that helps here.